# File path in Windows XP NTFS Format with batch for /F command

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

i try to figure out if i recognize enough reading the help and support center with this question.

Some informations are not linked in a for me reasonable way.

Reading about the Type command it was possible for me to recognize that using NTFS Format with my hard disk ,i have to use double quotes for path and file names with spaces.

I will show a batch code first without quotes and then with ,because with a for /F command this case double quoted do not match either with a echo command nor a type command.

```
@echo off
rem @
rem @
rem @

for /F %%A in (Textdokument.txt) do set Datei=%%A

rem @
rem @

echo %Datei%

rem @
rem @

echo.

rem @
rem @

set Datei=

rem @
rem @

pause
```

Workes proper.

The same example with double quotes just returns a ,file not found message.

```
for /F %%A in ("Dokumente und Einstellungen"\Benutzername\Desktop^\"Neuer Ordner"\Textdokument.txt) do set Datei=%%A
```

Building an easy base for gathering more reasonable file content leads to this question regarding all information i have read. To search further i would be lucky with a answer.

Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

`for /f %%a in (someFileName) ...` will consider `someFileName` as a file name to read, executing the code in the `do` clause for each of the lines in the file.

`for /f %%a in ("some file name") ....` will consider `"some file name"` as a inmediate string to process, executing the code in the `do` clause for only this string.

`for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("some file name") ...` will consider `"some file name"` as a file name to read, executing the code in the `do` clause for each of the lines in the file.

And, the quotes should enclose the full path, so your code should be

```
for /F "usebackq" %%A in (
    "Dokumente und Einstellungen\Benutzername\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\Textdokument.txt"
) do set Datei=%%A
```

Comment: Without using carriage return with notepad or carets the "usebackq" option was the best advice ,it returned the safed tokens from the Textfile.